# Dropbox hangs when trying to move sync folder

Tags: sync, dropbox, cinnamon, nemo

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with Cinnamon as desktop environment and Nemo as file manager.

Dropbox's default folder is `~/Dropbox`. When I try to move the folder, [by clicking the "Mover" (Move) button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2vRP.png), the computer hangs. The disk LED shows that the disk is working and it hangs so quickly that I can't even kill the process. I can only reboot the system.

Also, the selective sync functionality doesn't work and shows a gigantic window, and also hangs.